# Add Button for Selected Product Cards using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, e-commerce

I am working with e-commerce site. How do I add a button exclusively to product cards that contain audio file?

```js
var products = document.querySelectorAll('ul.products');
products.forEach(function(product){
    var voice = product.querySelectorAll('li.product > div.nv-card-content-wrapper');
    voice.forEach(function(item) {
        
      var btn = document.createElement('button');
      btn.className = 'play_audio';
      btn.textContent = "CLICK TO LISTEN";
      btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            
            item.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play();
        })
        if (!item.getElementsByTagName('audio')){
            btn.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
      item.appendChild(btn);
    });
})
```

This is the sample page: https://staging.buellairhorns.com/product-category/horns/page/2

Answer (score 0):

Just got it solved. I just need to change my condition from

```js
!item.getElementsByTagName('audio')
```

to

```js
!item.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]
```